# Sharded Azure SQL Database Split-Merge Tool

Tags: sql-server, azure

**Background**

I am developing a multi-tenant application that supports each Tenant having its own database and/or sharing a database with other Tenants.

The design is similar to this, though I doubt it follows the *exact* design Microsoft would prefer for use with Azure Elastic Database Tools ([image source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns#g-multi-tenant-app-with-sharded-multi-tenant-databases))

[image: sharded multi-tenant database diagram]

My "Host" database (Catalog in the diagram) knows each Tenants' TenantId and the Connection String associated with it. When a user navigates to a particular Tenant's login page, the application finds the associated Connection String and changes the context of the application to this Connection String.

Every record across all of the databases and tables references the TenantId that owns it. This is what allows for database-per-tenant and/or shared databases.

Each table within each database uses an auto-incrementing Integer Primary Key. I build the Foreign Key references between tables in the database using these auto-incrementing Primary Keys.

**Question**

My understanding is that it is easy (given my design) to *split* a particular Tenant out into its own database and then update the Connection String in the Catalog. However, I am just now realizing that *merging* a database with auto-incrementing Primary Keys will be a huge mess unless I re-calculate the Primary Keys and update all of the Foreign Key references before doing a merge of some sort.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625232/1984712) suggests that for the Azure Elastic Database Merge Tools "The values of autoincrement columns are not copied over, they will be regenerated at the destination. So new ids will be assigned to these rows." Unfortunately I can't find any additional information to back up this statement.

My question is this: Is the [Azure Split-Merge tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-overview-split-and-merge) actually smart enough to regenerate auto-incrementing Primary Keys and, if so, will it also update the Foreign Key references accordingly?

**edit:** I should mention that my application was not specifically designed to be dependent on Azure Elastic Database tools. If I can use them to merge/split, great. If not, that's ok too.